# Laravel login form - email is not correct

Tags: php, laravel, forms, session

When I try to login with a form in Laravel and save session to redirect in home page, I always get the message that the email required is not correct even if it is correct

This is the controller:

```
public function welcome (Request $request) {
    { 
        $this->validate($request, [

        'mail' => 'required|email',
        'mdp'=> 'required'
    ]);
    $patt= patient::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get() ;
    foreach ($patt as $log ) 
    {
        if (( $log->Login== $request->input('mail') ) && ( $log->Password== $request->input('mdp') ))
        {
            $request->session()->put('log_in', true);
            return redirect('index' , ['helloo'=>$log]);
        }

     return back()->withErrors([
        'message'=> 'Emails or password not correct!'
        ]) ;  }

}
```

Web.php:

```
Route::Post('/index' , 'patientcontroller@welcome')->name('rahmaa');
```

Form:

```
<form  class="form-signin" method="post" action="{{route('rahmaa')}}"> 
    @csrf  
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Adresse mail" data-rule="email" autofocus="" /> </br>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="mdp" placeholder="Mot de passe" data-rule="required"/>      

      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit"> Se connecter </button> <br>
     <center> <a href="inscription"> Inscrivez-vous </a>  </center> 
    </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you getting error mail is required because you'r sending email not mail. just change `mail` to `email`

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'mdp'=> 'required'
]);
```

or change input `name attribute` to `mail`

```
<input name="mail"/>
```

rewriten your function

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
....

public function welcome(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'mdp' => 'required',
        ]);

        // since email is unique. no need to grab all data
        $patient = patient::where('Login', $request->input('email'))->first();

        // if patient exists
        if ($patient) {

            // check hashed password
            // assuming $patient->Password hashed
            if (Hash::check($request->input('mdp'), $patient->Password)) {
                $request->session()->put('log_in', true);
                return redirect('index', compact('patient'));
            }
        }

        return back()->withErrors([
            'message' => 'Emails or password not correct!',
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: yeees it's work thank you but i got another error ; `Oops! Emails or password not correct!`   even if the mail and password are correct !!

Comment: You are comparing mdp with the patient password. first check whether the patient's password has been hashed or not. because if you compare mdp (string without hash) with a hashed password patient you will never meet the conditions

Comment: what i must add ?

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is `<input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" />`
The name of the input is "email", in the php you're searching "mail"

```
'mail' => 'required|email',
```

It should be:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="mail" />
```

Comment: yeees it's work thank you but i got another error ; Oops! Emails or password not correct! even if the mail and password are correct !!